# RecyclerView becomes empty after coming back to a destroyed activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a **recyclerview** that reads from a **Firebase database** a list of people and displays them on the layout. When I access to the activity for the first time it goes everything as expected, but when I finish the activity with the **BackButton** and when I try to access again to that activity, the recyclerview becomes empty.
Note that I try to add programmatically the people by using a Listener for a SingleValueEvent.

```
    class myActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var index = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fisio)

        Firebase.database.setPersistenceEnabled(true)
        val database = Firebase.database("mydatabase")
        val myRef = database.getReference("People")


        val peopleList = ArrayList<MyPeopleListAdapter.MyPeopleItem>()

        val code = intent.getStringExtra("key")

        val recview = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerViewF)
        recview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        val adapter = MyPeopleListAdapter(peopleList)
        recview.adapter = adapter
        recview.setHasFixedSize(true)


        myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {


                val ref = snapshot.child(code.toString()).getValue<Map<String, *>>()

                val peopleListRef = snapshot.child(code.toString()).child("PeopleList")

                peopleListRef.children.forEach {
                    val hash = it.getValue<Map<String,*>>()
                    val pId = it.key
                    val pFull = hash!!["Name"].toString()
                    val pEmail = hash["Email"].toString()
                    val pPic = hash["Pic"].toString()
                    val pS = hash["S"].toString()


                    peopleList.add(index, MyPeopleListAdapter.MyPeopleItem( 
                        pId.toString(),
                        pPic,
                        pFull,
                        pEmail,
                        pS))

                    adapter.notifyItemInserted(index)

                    index += 1

                }

            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                println(error.message)
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()

        finish()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the recycler view didn't had a **scrollToPosition()** method implemented. So after the adapter is notified, the scroll method is called and the code becomes:

```
// ... 

    adapter.notifyItemInserted(index)
    recview.scrollToPosition(0)

// ...
```